# How to import data from html to java REST full web serwices

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to take the information that users entered in html registration page and check it in REST full web services in java? I know the way how to check that information but I don't know how to take it?Thank you..

Comment: What's the difference between *check* and *take* ?

Comment: First i need to take that information and then to check it

Comment: Probably you can use Ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>JAX-RS @FormQuery Testing</h1>

    <form action="rest/user/add" method="post">
        <p>
            Name : <input type="text" name="name" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Age : <input type="text" name="age" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>  

  import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    @Path("/user")
    public class UserService {

        @POST
        @Path("/add")
        public Response addUser(
            @FormParam("name") String name,
            @FormParam("age") int age) {

            return Response.status(200)
                .entity("addUser is called, name : " + name + ", age : " + age)
                .build();

        }

    }


name and age here are form inputs of form page.
```